# Are there any funds tracking INDEXDJX:REIT?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, etf

I'm looking to get into real estate, and topic index seems promising on a 5-10 year scale.
Are there any ETFs, or mutual fund products offering to track this index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can't invest in an index, you can invest in a fund that basically invests in what the index is made up of. Example: In dealing with an auto index, you could find a fund that buys car companies's stock.
[The Google Finance list of funds dealing with INDEXDJX:REIT](http://www.google.com/finance?q=reit&restype=mutualfund&noIL=1)
Although not pertaining to your quetion exactly, you may want to consider buying into [Vanguard REIT ETF](http://www.google.com/finance?q=nyse:vnq)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: INDEXDJX:REIT is a specific index. You've included a search for just "reit", which is not quite what the OP asked for. REIT ETFs can vary a fair amount in what the underlying is invested in.